# Does a Titan vertex centric index have an effect on the performance of order?

Tags: gremlin, titan

Suppose I have a variable `v` which represents a vertex generating pipe and the vertices selected by `v` have edges named `related` that have a numeric property called `time`.  Also suppose I have defined a vertex centric index on `time` a la https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Vertex-Centric-Indices

`v.outE('related').order { it.a.time <=> it.b.time }`

Does the vertex centric index impact the performance of `order` in this case?

Comment: While stephen's answer works well, the simple and direct answer is YES, it does have a positive impact on the performance of `order`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `order` step is an in-memory function that is not "pushed-down" to Titan as part of a [Vertex Query](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Vertex-Query).  That said, I suppose that use of `order` may end up being redundant to the query if the order defined by the vertex centric index matches the order defined by the query.

Comment: Is there a way to control the ordering of the underlying vertex centric index?  Suppose I want the iterator to return these vertices in descending order by time.

Comment: Use `sortKey` - https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Type-Definition-Overview#sortkeytitantype-and-signaturetitantype

Comment: Didn't notice `sortOrder` before.  Excellent idea, stephen!